# Include ignored column in EFCore

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.1

I have a scenario where I'd wish to ignore a column (so that it get's not joined on every include etc.) but include it explicit if I need to. Selecting all the other columns needed on every join is not a practible solution for me. I store a user's profile picture in the DB and the owner, midifier etc. gets joined on almost every object, making some queries pretty slow.

Is there a best practice for this scenario?

Edit: I thought about creating a 2nd, *virtual* Model mapped to the same table containing only this one column but two models mapped to the same table seam to make some problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have added in you Edit section. That is how I solved a similar problem.
This works for me and it runs in production today.
And I can easy include the the Body filed when I need to.

```
   public class Content 
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string Preamble { get; set; }
        public virtual ContentBody Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContentBody
    {
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

This is where I do the Model mapping:

```
public class ContentMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Content>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Content> builder)
        {
            // Primary Key
            builder.ToTable("Content");
            builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            builder.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Property(p => p.Heading).HasColumnName("Heading");
            builder.Property(p => p.Preamble).HasColumnName("Preamble");

            // Relationships
            builder.HasOne(t => t.Body)
                .WithOne().HasForeignKey<ContentBody>(t => t.Id);
        }

    }  

    public class ContentBodyMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ContentBody>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ContentBody> builder)
        {
            // Primary Key
            builder.ToTable("Content");
            builder.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            builder.Property(p => p.Body).HasColumnName("Body");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... Though EF didn't like use of the same table a 2nd time? But I'll give it a try and mark as answer, if it works. What version of EF are you using?

Comment: I use EF Core 3.1

Comment: Feels a bit hacky, since EF responses are a bit unexpected - e.g. if content is empty the relation object is null? But nvmd, works like a charm! Thank you!